# Fake KeyPress Trigger in python

Tags: python, keypress

Is it possible to make a keypress trigger in python? and if so, then what's the simplest approach to make it?

What I'm trying to accomplish is just to make a simple fake trigger, that by executing a function makes the system listen that I've pressed the key.

for example that in a code, that I have pressed the 'Page Up' Key.
I am currently using Ubuntu 10.04
this is what I am looking for

```
#function for auto trigger key pressed
def autoPressedPageUp():
   pressed.key("PageUp")

#if it recieved a message from a network
#it will call the function of trigger
if recievedMessage:
   autoPressedPageUp()
```

is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5714072, http://stackoverflow.com/q/11150966, http://stackoverflow.com/q/11597892, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136734

Answer (score -1):

Way back in Visual Basic, there was a feature called SendKeys. SendKeys functionality has been implemented in many languages. I would try [this project](https://code.google.com/p/sendkeys-ctypes/) for python. Have not used it myself.